# How to best share updated html and csv files created in a Juypter notebook with colleagues

Tags: python, plotly, webdeploy

**What exactly I am doing:** updating a predictive model with new data bi-weekly, and then updating the csv file and plotly graphs (html files) that contain the new predictions

**What my problem is:** right now I am sharing these updated predictions either ad hoc over email or by uploading the files to google drive (or my often both). Neither is a very good solution so I am looking for a better way to programmatically update these files and share them with my colleagues

**My ideal solution:** a link I could share that would open a web page with all of this data updated. The link could either be something that you can't find without being given the exact link or something that required a username and password to access

Decent enough with python for data analysis and visualization but no experience deploying web apps. Thanks in advance